# Could not find declaration file for module grapesjs

Tags: reactjs, grapesjs

I'm trying to incorporate GrapesJs with React. I installed grapesjs using `npm i grapesjs` in node environment. But when I try to import it using `import grapesjs from "grapesjs"`, it doesn't import it and says that the declaration file for module  grapesjs is missing.

Answer (score 0):

check this [github issue](https://github.com/artf/grapesjs/issues/1180) . Looks similar to yours